# How to convert CLOB to image or vice versa?

Tags: java, image, oracle11g, clob

In Oracle 11g I have a table that has a CLOB column containing image data for each row.
I need to convert the CLOB field back to an image. I searched a bit through google but I could not find a working example.
Can anyone help please?

Thank you

Comment: Isn't BLOB better than CLOB for storing images?

Comment: Of course, I know, but I did not create the database, and now I have to deal with this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. This is what I used

```
public void convertFromClob(Clob c, File f2) {
    try {
        InputStream inStream = c.getAsciiStream();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(inStream, sw);

        // Transfer the data
        byte[] data = Base64.decodeBase64(sw.toString());
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", f2);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You can call directly the above method passing as parameters your Clob variable and the File to store the image. Tung